# find out default .Net encoding from command line

Tags: .net, character-encoding

Is there a way to find out the value of the default encoding (i.e. `System.Text.Encoding.Default.BodyName`) from the command line or some other method other than writing a program?

Comment: I think the closest you can get is to use the command line to query registry for the "Active Code Page".  i.e:  "reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage /v ACP".

Comment: Is there any documentation about the relationship of that registry setting to the value of Encoding.Default?

Comment: I do not know of documentation that directly states that the Encoding.Default is based on that setting, but if you look at the source code for [Encoding.Default](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,1c75de327ad88c0a) and follow its call path you will see that it calls the API function [GetACP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070(v=vs.85).aspx) that is part of the NLS functions.  Furthermore you can look at the documentation for the [ACP value](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976085.aspx) and draw your own conclusion,